# Independence between random variables and set

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb P)$ be a probability space, and $X$ is a random variable in this space.

For a set $A\in \mathcal F$, can we conclude that

"$X$ is independent with $A$" $<=>$"$\int_AXd\mathbb P=\mathbb E(X)\mathbb P(A)$"?

I mean if these two statements are equivalent？

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If $X$ is zero mean and $A:=\{X=0\}$, then we have $0=\mathbb E[X\chi(A)]=\mathbb E[X]\mathbb P(A)$. If $\mathbb P(A)\in (0,1)$, then $A$ is not independent of itself, hence it cannot be independent of the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X$.

Comment: thanks for your explanation !